# UnitTesting help: using stub?

Tags: unit-testing

I have a question concerning unit testing.

I have to test a function, call it function A, that receives as input an instance of a class B, and returns true or false.

Now in my test I have to somehow create an object to pass to the function A; what I'm currently doing is to initialize the class B using its constructor and calling some of its methods to populate it, create the right structures, etc. and then pass it to the function A. Now, I'm not sure that this is a good pattern: in particular what happens if there's a bug in one the methods of class B, or I change its interface?

So I guess I would need to use a stub; but it seems weird to write a class that has basically the same structures of my class B; also the function A will ultimately work with the class B, so if I change the interface of class B then the test for function A should crash to tell me to change function A to accommodate the new interface.

What is the correct pattern to use?

NOTE: If you think this is primarily opinion based, please reformulate the question as: "According to the principles advocated in "The Art of Unit Testing", what would be the best thing to do here?" - for the rest of you who are sane, feel free to write an answer with a larger perspective

**Edit**

I should clarify, the sole purpose of function A is to take an instance of class B and verify that a certain condition is met. Now, I could create a stub in place of class B, but I am not sure this would make sense; it seems rather pointless. On the other hand to initialize B I do something like classB.addData(randomData); what happens if this code fails? I will get an error in the test for function A while the actual problem is in the initialization of class B

**Edit 2**
Some code that shows more explicitly what the function does. The real code is exactly the same, except the methods are more complicated but otherwise it's exactly the same

```
def functionA(objectB):
    return objectB.data < 10

def testFunctionA():
      objectB = classB()
      objectB.addData(19)      #Is this a problem or should I stub objectB?

      assert(functionA(objectB) is False)
```

Comment: i think you need to post something concrete for a concrete answer.  Right now the question is all abstract and theory, which lends itself to an abstract answer.  If you need a concrete answer, code that demonstrates the problem would be useful.

Comment: @Kritner I added some code.. The real code is essentially identical to this; the methods may be longer but is essentially the same

Comment: is this python?  I don't know python, but I'm guessing `functionA` returns `true` when `objectB.data` gt 10, and `false` otherwise... if that is the would wouldn't your assert fail?

Comment: *what happens if there's a bug in one the methods of class B* That has NOTHING do with **this** test you are writing, This is called **unit**-testing. So you shouldn't care about *another* unit. You test the methods of class B individually. That's basically what unit testing is. If all your test pass, then you have nothing to worry about. Yet if all all your tests are passing, but still something isn't working, then it only means either you are testing the wrong thing or not testing enough or you wrote your tests wrong. What matters is your understanding that these should be dealt separately!

Comment: In addition if the implementation of B changes then as long 'as its test don't fail', meaning with the same interface, your functions are still working as should then you have nothing to worry about. However if you change the implementation of B and it fails, then your code is failing at another test (which requires refactoring), which again is irrelevant to the functionA test.

Comment: @Honey My point was that if the method of class B fails, then two tests fail: the one testing the method in class B, and the one testing function A; plus, the one testing function A doesn't fail where is supposed to, fails in another point. Isn't this something we should avoid? Kind of like having multiple assert in a same test, reason for which Parametrized test were developed.Another reason is that I am relying on the correct behaviour of B to test A, and isn't this also something we should avoid? Shouldn't test be as separate as possible?

Comment: @Kritner Yes it's python. My bad, it was a typo :) I corrected it with "<" now :)

Comment: @Ant Yes 2 tests fail, but one is upstream to the other. figuring it out shouldn't be difficult. If you wipe out class B and then start testing you would have a bunch of tests fails. Something failing 2 tests isn't necessarily bad. Leaking the testing of function to another is bad. When you write tests you write them to only catch bugs within the domain of what you intend to test. If not then maybe Class B is also dependent on ClassC and that is also dependent on class D there would be no end.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the most powerful tool in the unit testing toolbox is dependency injection, and that fits perfectly here.

When constructing an object, all its collaborator objects should be passed to its constructor in the form of interface references. In your case the unit to be tested is a function, but the principle is the same. The functions collaborator objects are passed to it in the same manner.

If your test object only collaborates with other objects through interfaces, it is possible to pass mock objects in unit testing. Also, frameworks like google mock makes it very convenient to create mocks, and write clean test cases where the expected interactions are easy to understand.

If this is what you meant, then yes, that is a good pattern.

Edit:

This is how i would write the test function.

```
def functionA(objectB):
    return objectB.data < 10

def testFunctionA():
      objectB = fakeClassB()
      EXPECT_CALL(objectB, data).WillOnce(Return(19))
      assert(functionA(objectB) is False)
```

Instead of passing a real classB object, pass a fakeClassB object. This makes the test depending on the interface of classB rather than the actual implementation of classB. A failing test is caused by a faulty use of the interface and not some implementation detail n classB. Depending on what language you are working with, this could be possible or not i suppose.

Another perk is build complexity. You can build the test function without building the implementation of classB. You only need to build the interface of classB and the fakeClassB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) In this case I don't need dependency injection, because my function sole purpose is to test instances of the class B. My question is, when testing function A, should I initialize actual instances of the class B (and call something like classB.addData(randomData)) or create a stub in place of class B to pass to the function A?

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

in the scope of ***unit*** testing `A`, `B`s implementation should not matter.  Using a mock/stub/whatever in order to test the different branches of `A` is fine.

If `B`s implementation at some point changes, that should not matter in regards to `A`s implementation (in an ideal scenario, but your example is very abstract).  If `B`s implementation were to be significantly changed in so much that `A` is looking at different members of `B`, then yes, you could have an impact to `A`s unit tests.  If `B`s implementation of arriving at the members that `A` relies on changes, that will not matter with a mocked version of `B`.

It ***will*** however matter to `B`s unit tests.

If you have anything concrete I can elaborate, but right now it's mostly just an abstract answer for an abstract question.

```
def functionA(objectB):
    return objectB.data < 10

def testFunctionA():
      objectB = classB()
      objectB.addData(19)      #Is this a problem or should I stub objectB?

      assert(functionA(objectB) is False)
```

is this python? I don't know python, but I'm guessing functionA returns true when objectB.data lt 10, and false otherwise.

Given all of that, `functionA` is still only returning a `true` or `false` based on a member of `objectB`.  How `objectB.data` gets its data is not relevant to the scope of unit testing `functionA`, so `objectB.data` can and should (where possible) be mocked/stubbed in order to get a true ***unit test***.  Integration test is another story (you should use the real implementation for that, but your question was specific to unit testing)

Comment: Thanks for you answer! My main problem is that I don't think it makes sense for me to create a stub for class B, since the sole purpose of function A is to get an instance of class B and do something with it. On the other hand I am not sure, because to initialize class B I do something like classB.addData(randomData); what happens if that code fails?

Comment: So you suggest using a stub instead of creating classB using its constructor?

Comment: stub, mock, fake, anything that isn't the actual implementation in order to achieve an actual unit test

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule in testing: `mock all units other than the tested one`. The point of mocking is to provide some correct output values when you would call units that are used in the `tested` unit. You should explicitly provide some samples that you know are correct, so that the `tested` unit can not fail because of some fail caused of the unit used by it.